# Displaying an array Meteor Helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

For each question I'm trying to display the choices array in an li using Meteor Helpers.

MongoDB my collection is:

```
{ "_id" : "AS7zMpdqWzpRyzdDw", "question" : "Favorite Color?", "answer" : "Blue", "choices" : [ "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Black" ] }
{ "_id" : "RaDxyRjDyL4at6oN4", "question" : "Favorite Truck?", "answer" : "Ram", "choices" : [ "Silverado", "Tundra", "Ram", "Titan" ] }
{ "_id" : "n6kvXfoLKueTZiR2A", "question" : "Favorite Animal?", "answer" : "Dog", "choices" : [ "Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "Fish" ] }
```

code for the helper is

```
Template.genKnow.helpers({
question(){
    return GenKnow.find({});
},
```

});

code for the html is

```
    {{#each question}}
<div id="testQuestions">
    <div class="question" id="question">
        <h3 id="quesNum">QUESTION</h3>
        <p id="questions">{{question}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="choices">
        <h3>CHOICES</h3>
        <ol id="choices">
            <li>{{choices}}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
        <h3>CORRECT ANSWER</h3>
        <p id="answer">{{answer}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

[screen shot of what it is returning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJszf.png)

For choices it is returning

```
1. Blue, Green, Red, Black
```

I want it to return

```
1. Blue
2. Green
3. Red
4. Black
```

I tried

```
<div class="choices">
        <h3>CHOICES</h3>
        <ol id="choices">
            {{#each {{choices}} }}
                <li></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ol>
    </div>
```

got error message

```
        <div class="choices">
        <h3>CHOICES</h3>
        <ol id="choices">
            {{#each question.choices }}
                <li></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ol>
    </div>
```

still error

Any idea how to get the array to return as a li item?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a meteor methods to perform the query where you have return GenKnow.find ({});
I would query using a

```
Template.genKnow.helpers({
question(){
    Meteor.call('meteorMethod', dataObject, function(error, success) { 
        if (error) { 
            console.log('error', error); 
        } 
        if (success) { 
          for (var i = 0; i < success.length; i++) {
              var element = success[i];
              return element
          }

        } 
    });
},
```

Then there in my method

```
Meteor.methods({ 
    meteorMethod: function() { 
         Return GenKnow.find ({this.userId}) fetch ();
    } 
});
```

Comment: You should not call a method in a helper, but in an event handler or in component lifecycle hooks (or some other place where handling and mutating state is appropriate).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I had to do some tweeking and wounded up using a forEach to display the choices array.  It seems to be working.  Appreciate it!